# Problem with IE 9 Download Manager

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, download, download-manager

I just noticed that since Windows Update auto downloaded a new update for the latest version of Internet Explorer 9, the built in download manager stops downloading videos (any video, from any site) at around 97%.

And, upon clicking cancel, it doesn't really cancel it. It appears to have cancelled it, but later when I download a program or a file or something, it says 3 (for example) downloads remaining. But there's only one download in the list.

Has anybody else had this problem with IE9?

How can I "reset" the IE9 Download Manager, or "reset" IE9 without uninstalling (preferably)?

Comment: Yaay I got an upvote lol!

Comment: I faced the same thing. When launching any Citrix application, it shows downloading the connector and then stays indefinitely at 99%. Does not clear even after clearing the download list.

Comment: @Arjan: "Don't judge a question by its cov^H^H^Htitle."

Comment: (I'm not sure "Problem with" is a good summary, @Mayank, but at least it's less of a rant indeed so still thanks for that edit! Ah, you edited the question too. Good!)

Comment: "Problem with" is best used in this case I believe, since the actual "problem" is not clear, and the "problem" occurs in different situations. So, if you want a title the is more relevant and descriptive, it'll be about 5 pages long...

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your anti-virus for testing, as the download may be sitting at 97% percent while the file is being scanned.  Videos can be very large and if the anti-virus is scanning them it could take a while for the download to completely 'finish'.

You also may want to check out the Windows' [Resource Monitor](http://www.win7articles.com/windows-7-resource-monitor.html) while a problem download is hanging, as it may tell you what's going on.