# My computer stops every download at 99%

Tags: internet, download

Whenever I start any downloading it stop on 99% and never completes. I changed my download manger and stopped firewall, but all in vain. Problem contiunes to persist. What is causing this problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Try adding some details about your environment such as OS and downloading method.

Comment: Similar: [Problem with IE 9 Download Manager](http://superuser.com/questions/269307/problem-with-ie-9-download-manager?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this last week, they would get to 99% and then "fail", or just sit forever.  As Daniel Hicks suggests, it was the Anti-virus.

I found that if I went and renamed the .partial files Internet Explorer makes, the files actually worked fine.

Disabled the anti-virus and files started downloading fine.  Replaced it with a different (newer) AV product and they've been fine since.

So, perhaps try temporarily disabling or uninstalling your current AV package.

Comment: He doesn't have anti virus...

Comment: I have no **Anti Virus** in my computer.